# Sort Kendo Grid JQuery using Compare - Position the Null Values Last When Sorting

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying sort numbers in Kendo using compare, goal is **Position the Null Values Last When Sorting**.

based on the example when I'm sorting the string values it is perfectly fine, but when I'm trying to apply it into a numbers, It's not working properly.
[Please see the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIFww.png)

**In example, the number 10 is considered as null.**

Here is the example: https://dojo.telerik.com/ILipALAG/2

Here is the [link](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-sort-null-value-end) from Kendo that I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `sortable.compare` function:

```
sortable: {
  compare: function (a, b, desc) {
    if (a.level === 10)
      return desc ? -1 : 1;
    else if (b.level === 10)
      return desc ? 1 : -1;
    else if (a.level === b.level)
      return 0;
    else if (a.level > b.level)
      return 1;
    else if (b.level > a.level)
      return -1;                        
  }
}
```

This should put the number 10 at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you so much. it works! you save my day :)